# If $x\in X$ and sequence $(x_n) \in X^{\Bbb N}$ converges in $(X,d)$ , then so does every subsequence of $(x_n)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

A subequence of a sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is a sequence $ (x_{n_1}, x_{n_2},x_{n_3},...$) where $n_1,n_2,n_3,... \in \Bbb N$ with $n_1\lt n_2\lt n_3\lt ...$

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $x\in X$. Prove that if $x\in X$ and sequence $(x_n) \in X^{\Bbb N}$ converges to $x$ in $(X,d)$ , then so does every subsequence of $(x_n)$.

**Defnition:** Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, let $(x_n)\in X^{\Bbb N}$ and let $x\in X$.
We say that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ in $(X, d)$,
if $\forall  B\in \mathscr B(x) : x_n\in B $ eventually

Comment: What have you tried? What does it mean for the sequence to converge to $x$? What would it mean for a subsequence to converge to $x$?

Comment: $\mathscr B(x)$ is the set of all balls centerd at $x$ with raduis r

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : I used the above definition but  I couldn't deduce that every subsequence is converges to the same limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that for each $\epsilon >0$ we can find $N$ which makes $d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$ by taking $n\geq N$. Consider a subsequence $\langle x_{n_j}\rangle$. Since $n_1<n_2<\dots$, there must exist a $J$ for which $n_j\geq N$ whenever $j\geq J$. In such as case, what can you say about $$d(x_{n_j},x)\text{ ? }$$

Comment: $d(x_{n_j},x)\text{  }< \epsilon$... so $(x_{n_j})$ converges to $x$... thank u

Answer (score 2):

Note that "$x_n\in\mathscr B$ eventually" means the same as "There are at most finitely many $n$ with $x_n\notin \mathscr B$". If this holds for the full sequence, it must even more so hold for a subsequence.